# SQL JSON Parsing using OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, rdbms

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max)  = N'[
  {
    "p1": {
      "name": "mike",
      "age": 34,
      "address": "berlin"
    },
    "p2": {
      "name": "david",
      "age": 45,
      "address": "munich"
    },
    "p3": {
      "name": "rachel",
      "age": 15,
      "address": "frankfurt"
    }
  }
]'
```

I need to parse the above JSON to a table like below using SQL query (SQL Sever). Please help!

| name | age | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mike | 34 | berlin |
| david | 45 | munich |
| rachel | 15 | frankfurt |

Comment: What's *wrong* with `OPENJSON`? You mention it in the title; why isn't `OPENJSON` working for you?

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON content has this fixed structure (a JSON array with a single element), a combination of two `OPENJSON()` calls and an additional `APPLY` operator returns the expected results:

```
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0]') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   name nvarchar(100),
   age int,
   address nvarchar(100)
) j2
```